# Receiving Java error "cannot find symbol" in MVC package

Tags: java, model-view-controller, windows, java-package

Sorry, I'm sure this is some rookie istake I'm making but I have a MVC pattern package which keeps returning this errors to me:

```
======================================
hrms.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        hrmsModel HRMSModel = new hrmsModel();
        ^
  symbol:   class hrmsModel
  location: class HRMS
hrms.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        hrmsModel HRMSModel = new hrmsModel();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class hrmsModel
  location: class HRMS
hrms.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        hrmsView view = new hrmsView(HRMSModel);
        ^
  symbol:   class hrmsView
  location: class HRMS
hrms.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        hrmsView view = new hrmsView(HRMSModel);
                            ^
  symbol:   class hrmsView
  location: class HRMS
4 errors
=======================================
```

Would really appreciate if you could tell me what I was doing wrongly here...Thanks in advance! I've added the code for the main package of my class hrms MVC gui below, for your reference.

Comment: Share your package name and class name for hrms

Comment: I added them, kindly take a look

Comment: check my answer, your object creation syntax is wrong.

Comment: [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is a better place to learn Java. Posting syntax errors on SO will no get you very far.

Answer (score 0):

`hrmsModel HRMSModel = new hrmsModel();` 
seems like its not arrange properly.

I think the right arrarangement is this `YourClass yourVariable = new YourClass()`

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have the classes `hrmsModel` and `hrmsView` in the same package as `HRMS`. If you don't have them, you should import them.

On a side note, it's best if you follow the Java naming convention and name your class `HRMSModel` and your variable `hrmsModel`. If you are following that convention, then you might be confusing the order of both and that's why the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for object creation is:

```
ClassName instanceName = new ClassName();
```

So change this

```
hrmsModel HRMSModel = new hrmsModel();
```

to:

```
HRMSModel hrmsModel = new HRMSModel();
```

Comment: Do u have all class files in directory called hrms?

Answer (score 0):

Under hrms package you have HRMS* java, but you are trying to create object for hrms* classes.

Change name and execute.